# dynamic_cast fails between "long distance" siblings on linux compilation

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, dynamic-cast

There is a class ***DerivedClass*** which inherits from both ***BaseClassA*** and ***BaseClassB*** publicly. All classes have virtual functions to make sure the virtual table is built properly.

***BaseClassA*** and ***BaseClassB*** are located in *Library1* and ***DerivedClass*** is in *Library2*.

One function in *Library1* retrieves a ***DerivedClass*** in the form of a ***BaseClassA*** pointer and tries to dynamic_cast to ***BaseClassB*** but it fails. The same function works in different environments and compilers (visual studio for instance).

Extra information:

- Reproduced with 4.1.2 and 4.5 gcc versions (read about the old gcc bug)
- Derived class name is "Match" (thought it may collide with other library? python?)
- There are tens of libraries compiling one after the other while linking between them.
- *nm -gC*: Found the vtable address for *Match*
- gdb (7.0.1): used to check the vtable address for the class but couldn't understand much. (gdb version doesnt support "info vtbl". gdb can't show direct information about the class claiming it is a typedef)
- *readelf -s*: I saw the symbol

I figured it might be one of the following problems

1. duplicated symbol
2. HIDDEN symbol somewhere in the libraries linked
3. Duplicated vtables
4. -E and RTLD_GLOBAL dlopen flag [linker flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#dso) didn't work (the linking is made using the makefile linker stage and probably not the dlopen.
5. [non-inline function manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060858/rtld-local-and-dynamic-cast-on-linux) (didnt work as well - but could be my mistake with understanding what exactly has to be done)

Been farming the web trying to find a solution. But what I want to know first is What Is The Problem? How can I focus on it?

(5) looks promising even though I didnt manage to use it.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated (a solution would be great as well ;) )

Comment: Try to reproduce with a minimal program (and post that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently #4 was the answer.
The was a hidden feature that loads functions dynamically and had to be handles separately. Adding the -Wl,-E flags to the linking process and changing the loader flags did the trick.

What I want to know if there is any linuxy way of understanding this is the error.

Something like "ldd" command or others (top, nm, readelf, etc) that I tried but couldn't see anything that pointed to this exact error.

Thanks SOF for continuous help in various subjects